# Compex SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a cities table:

```
cities(..., name, x, y, ...)
```

And users table:

```
users(..., city-name, ....)
```

In addition, I have 2 variables, C and R.
The first one contains a city name and the second contains a radius.
I need to formulate efficient SQL query that selects all users in radius R from a city C.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you have a go at doing the sql yourself and post what you come up with, that way we can see what you are struggling with..

Comment: wot is radius? could you provide a sample output?

Comment: Which table C and R exists? What is the relation of x and y in cities table?

Comment: For an efficient query you need a well designed schema, that is in Users you should use the ID of Cities - as a FK (indexed) - instead of the city-name.

Comment: @Nithesh
The city:
London X=300 Y=200
Is in radius 50 from Croydon (X=310 Y=215), because:
sqrt((300-310)^2 + (200-215)^2) = 18 < 50

Comment: @bajy assumung cityname is unique then why? Some would argue that the opposite is true!

Comment: @zeharon - I think you've just answered your own question!?!

Comment: @bajy there is id, you can use it instead the name if you want
C exists at cities
cities(id x name x X x Y)

I understand the logic, but how can I formulate the SQL query?

Comment: @Strawberry City name unique? How many London, Cambridge, etc. there are in the world? :)

Comment: In the world? Maybe millions. In the table? Maybe just one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a crude distance calculation:-

```
SELECT
FROM Users
INNER JOIN Cities UsersCities
ON Users.CityName = UsersCities.CityName
INNER JOIN Cities
ON SQRT(POW((Cities.x-UsersCities.X), 2) + POW((Cities.y-UsersCities.Y), 2)) < someradiusconverted
WHERE Cities.CityName = somecityname
```

Not going to work at the extreme ends of longitude (e.g. if a user's `x` coordinate is 179 and the city's is -179), plus you need to calculate the radius from mile to something that works with longitude / latitude calculations.

Using the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) will be less efficient but far more accurate:

```
SELECT Users.*
FROM Users
INNER JOIN Cities UsersCities
ON Users.CityName = UsersCities.CityName
INNER JOIN Cities
ON ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( Cities.y ) ) * cos( radians( UsersCities.Y ) ) * cos( radians( UsersCities.X ) - radians( Cities.x ) ) + sin( radians( Cities.y ) ) * sin( radians( UsersCities.Y ) ) ) ) < someradius
WHERE Cities.CityName = somecityname
```

Comment: Try now (but not tested as I have no real idea what your databases are like)

Answer (score 0):

I would think something on the line of:

```
select
    user_id
from
    Users
where
    city_id in (
        select
            city_id
        from
            Cities
        where
            sqrt(((select x from Cities where name = "London") - x)^2 + ((select y from Cities where name = "London")-y)^2) < 50
);
```

Comment: It's the most efficient from all suggested...
Try suggest something more efficient...

Comment: From a performance point of view, in my experience the use of the subquery is safer than using a join as this should force the optimisers to come up with the best plan, which is finding the nearby cities first.

Comment: From *"all suggested"*? I see only this answer ... And you waited, what, 23 minutes?

Comment: That looks like it is using a co related sub select (using x from Users in the inner select) and these normally perform badly

Comment: @ypercube, 1 answer may be "all suggested".
I assure, after 24 hours this answer will be "all suggested" ;)

Comment: @zeharon: Are you positive about that or just saying it to provoke someone to come up with a better suggestion?